# Writing GraphML with XOM?

Tags: java, xml, xom, graphml

I'm trying to write out a graphML document with XOM in java, but I can't figure out how to get all of the namespace declarations correct. To have valid graphML, I need to have a root element that looks like the following:

```
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
     http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
```

I've been able to get most of this by doing

```
Element root = new Element("graphml");
root.setNamespaceURI("http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns");
root.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

The problem is the last element of this tag, the `xsi:schemaLocation`. I can't figure out how to express this in XOM. I can't do it as a normal attribute, as that throws an exception(`Attribute prefixes must be declared.`) and doing it as an additional namespace declaration also results in an exception(`NCNames cannot contain colons`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it. Basically you didn't provide the namespace URI for `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute. Thus trying to create a prefixed attribute with no namespace which clearly won't work.

```
root.addAttribute(new Attribute("xsi:schemaLocation",
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd"));
```

Check here for the correct Attribute constructor

[`Attribute(String name, String URI, String value)`](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/Attribute.html#Attribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks, this works for implementing the sitemaps.org validation. http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html